# Non-english text size too small in windows 7

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, vcl, delphi-xe8

I am trying to display the current date in Nepali language. I have declared constant string for the caption. It renders the text pretty fine on windows 8.1 but the same text is displayed too small in windows 7. Adjusting the font size also doesn't help much as it should.

**Things I tried**

1. Installed Nepali language pack for windows 7
2. Installed several Unicode fonts like arial unicode ms, segoe ui, microsoft neo gothic and others
3. The source code has been saved as UTF-8 encoding

But the problem remains same.

Windows 8.1 output:

[image]

Windows 7 output:

[image]

There are two labels on the form. One is used to display the current temperature("segoe ui" font) which renders pretty fine on both the windows versions while the other one is used for displaying the date that has the actual problem.

**Edit**

How to create issue?

- create a new vcl form application project
- Drop a label and a button
- On button click change the caption of the label

sample code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const text = 'आइतबार कार्तिक २७ गते २०७२';
begin
  Label1.Caption := text;
end;
```

The font property for label has been set to: @Microsoft NeoGothic,11,[B],ANSI_CHARSET,clWindowText

By the way, this font doesn't exist in windows 7, I installed it and other ones as well but this couldn't help.

SO the question is, "How to display the caption in similar fashion in windows 7"

Comment: In order for us to help, we will have to try to replicate your program. That means we need to spend time writing that program, just to begin to contemplate helping. That's a hurdle. Not everyone will want to jump the hurdle.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with an MCVE to recreate your issue. Without it, it's just a game of a million guesses.

Comment: Also useful to know - VCL or FMX?  What is the display scaling setting on the Win8.1 computer?  On the Win7 computer?  On your development system?  If VCL, what is the `Scaled` property of your form set to?

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: @J... The scaled property is set to True as per default. I am executing the same app in my single computer. The main os is win 8.1 and the win7 is installed in virtualbox. I tried to run the same app in other win7 pc as well. It's same problem there.

Comment: Ok, but what are the display scaling settings on both systems?  Do you know what these are and where to set them?

Comment: I am doing this for the first time. As said earlier, both the windows are installed in the same desktop machine. The screen resolutions are same (1366*768). I also tried to disable **scaled** property but this couldn't help.

Comment: Go to *Start > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display*. What is the scaling set to on both systems? 100%, 125%, or 150%? Then go to "Set custom text size (DPI)", what is it set to on both systems?

Comment: On windows 7, it's 100% in  **Set custom text size (DPI)** and 100% scaling in Appearance and Personalization>Display.  The same setting is there in windows 8.1 as well.

Comment: Do you see the same difference in other applications with the same font? F.ex. if you set the same font in Notepad. And when testing with your application, you are testing the same .exe, aren't you?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes you are right. I copied the same text into windows 7 and opened it using notepad then found that windows 7 renders the given unicode(non-English) text too small.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use a font start starts with an @-sign? Fonts that start with an @-sign are vertically oriented fonts. I don't think you want to use these here.

Comment: @SebastianZ Let's say that the string is received through a HTTP request and I must display the text as it is.

Comment: Does that http request send you a font name that starts with the "@"?

Comment: using GET request I get json data. I parse the value and display the result. **Sample:**  "message": "\u0906\u091c \u092c\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0938\u093f\u0932\u094b\u0928\u093e \u0930 \u0930\u093f\u092f\u0932 \u092e\u0921\u094d\u0930\u093f\u0921\u0915\u094b \u092d\u093f\u0921\u0928\u094d\u0924",

Comment: The server doesn't send any font name. I just pasted the font property of the label from object inspector here. There is nothing like "@" symbol. I just pasted whatever the font property is.